# why I use this cql import csv data failed?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql

I try to import relationships data use csv file which contains 25000 rows , then I use this cypher:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://127.0.0.1:88/static/relations/261.csv' AS line  
MATCH (a:user{value:line.userId}),(b:device{value:line.deviceId})  
MERGE (a)-[rel:myrelname]->(b)  
WITH rel, COALESCE(rel.eventOccurTime, []) + line.eventOccurTime AS eventOccurTime
UNWIND eventOccurTime as r0
WITH rel, collect(distinct r0) AS unique
set rel.eventOccurTime= unique ,rel.business_name='data-test'
```

after 30 minutes ,I get this error:
**[Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed]: Connection reset, reference 0b8a3600-d715-44bf-8c5b-4260edeab459.**

how can I fix it ?

Comment: what happens if you do it with a smaller dataset? does it store your data as it should ?

Comment: relationships is stored,but the relationship's properties didn't stored .
When the amount of my CSV data is 5000 and the CQL is execueted sucessfully without errors, the properties can be stored. But in other case, I am not sure.

Comment: Note that when you UNWIND an empty array, the rest of your query is no longer executed. Could this be an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to try:

1. Simplify (and speed up) the query. There is no need to unwind and then re-collect the distinct elements of the list. And there is no need to create temporary lists or to append to lists unless really necessary.

   ```
   USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://127.0.0.1:88/static/relations/261.csv' AS line  
   MATCH (a:user{value: line.userId}), (b:device{value: line.deviceId})  
   MERGE (a)-[rel:myrelname]->(b)
   SET
     rel.business_name='data-test',
     rel.eventOccurTime = CASE
       WHEN rel.eventOccurTime IS NULL THEN [line.eventOccurTime]
       WHEN line.eventOccurTime IN rel.eventOccurTime THEN rel.eventOccurTime
       ELSE rel.eventOccurTime + line.eventOccurTime END
   ```
2. You may want to improve performance by creating [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on:

   - `:user(value)`
   - `:device(value)`
3. Use [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) to analyze the execution plan generated from your Cypher.

Comment: Thanks for you advice! I've tried your query, the execution time of the your code didn't seem to be significantly improved (before:33 minutes after:31 minutes), but your code is indeed much simpler than mine.

Comment: Did you add the indexes?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add  indexes. With indexes, it has a big significant improvement (before:33 minutes after:2 minutes), your advice helped me a lot, thank you very much!